Unable to login after Artifactory upgrade
I have an Artifactory install running 6.12.2 that uses LDAP for authentication and hosts a couple of Maven repos. I just tried to do an upgrade to 7.84.14 using the procedure from: https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/artifactory-version-6.x-to-7.x-upgrade-in-windows.  The upgrade seemed to work fine and I'm able to open the web UI. However, I can't browse my repos nor log in.  I checked the logs, but there are no errors indicating why I can't log in.  Is there someplace else to check? What could be wrong?

Sounds like you may not be connected to the correct DB.
Can you login with the default admin password?
You can always recreate the default admin user following this guide: https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-platform-administration-documentation/recreate-the-default-admin-user
This will allow you to now look at your LDAP settings and run some further tests.
I do want to note that LDAP logic moved from the Artifactory to Access micro service so you might need to look at the access-service.log and access-request .log to see the LDAP errors.
